# Google Maps v3 map.getBounds().containsLatLng is not a function

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

How do i set the "setMap" function here to port this code to v3? Or port it generally to v3...

// map recenter, if element is outside the mapscreen

```
while ((!map.getBounds().containsLatLng(marker.getPosition())) & (showAllCategoryElements == 0)) {
        var newCenterPointLng = (map.getBounds().getCenter().lng() + marker.getPosition().lng()) / 2;
        var newCenterPointLat = (map.getBounds().getCenter().lat() + marker.getPosition().lat()) / 2;
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(newCenterPointLat, newCenterPointLng));
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(newCenterPointLat, newCenterPointLng));
        if (!map.getBounds().containsLatLng(marker.getPosition())){
            map.zoomOut();
        }
```

here is an example http://d.hatena.ne.jp/tsmsogn/20111216/1324026723
some tips: markus.tao.at/geo/google-maps-api-v3-is-in-town/

i also import https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon js to get "containsLatLng" support

Thanks for help or tips

Answer (score 4):

Per the API documentation, .getbounds() returns a google.maps.LatLngBounds not a maps.Polygon.

You don't need the extra import as LatLngBounds has a contains function.

```
map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()) ....
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Answer (score 2):

In Google maps v3 we have another metho.
Here is the best example for you.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation